# TypeError when trying to send email with text

Tags: python, smtp

I tried to create program, into which will people upload some .txt files, and the text from .txt file will be sent to my email via SMTP. Im using gmail. I do not have much experience with programming and I want to learn more, so please help me. `:)`

I have 2 working codes, first code is locating & reading .txt file and second code is sending email.

```
import smtplib
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *

Tk().withdraw()
token = askopenfilename()
with open(token) as f:
    msg = f.readlines()
print(msg)
```

---

```
##########MAIL##############################################################
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login("MYEMAIL", "PASS")

server.sendmail("MYEMAIL", "MYEMAIL", msg)
server.quit()
```

Both codes work, I only need to combine them. This code is giving me error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JiriC\Desktop\name V1.1.py", line 19, in <module>
    server.sendmail("MYEMAIL", "MYEMAIL", msg)
  File "E:\PROGRAMY\PYTHON\lib\smtplib.py", line 882, in sendmail
    (code, resp) = self.data(msg)
  File "E:\PROGRAMY\PYTHON\lib\smtplib.py", line 564, in data
    q = _quote_periods(msg)
  File "E:\PROGRAMY\PYTHON\lib\smtplib.py", line 176, in _quote_periods
    return re.sub(br'(?m)^\.', b'..', bindata)
  File "E:\PROGRAMY\PYTHON\lib\re.py", line 192, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: `msg` should be a string. `readlines()` returns a list.

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
msg = f.read()
```

instead of:

```
msg = f.readlines()
```

That's because `sendmail()` wants a *string*, as the message suggests, but what `readlines()` is returning is a *list of strings*.

When you do `print(msg)` you will see `['first line', 'second line', ...]`. Instead, you should see the entire message without any brackets or quotes.

`read()` will correctly read the whole file and return its content as a single string.